# ssh ControlMaster exceptions

Tags: ssh

Most ssh connections I make benefit from the ControlMaster being turned on, for example most of the connections I make over VPN.  However, there are a few that don't, such as github.  So I've got the following in my ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host *
  ControlMaster auto
  ControlPath   ~/.ssh/%r,%h,%p
  ControlPersist 30m

Host github.com
  ControlMaster no
  ControlPath none
  ControlPersist no
```

(Among other such exceptions)

However, from what I can tell (pgrep -fla mux), the mux process is still being created, and this seems to provide some minor annoyances for the connections that don't benefit from muxing.

Is there some way to specify, on a host-by-host basis, in my config file, not to create the master connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first matching parameter applies. Switch the order of the sections.

```
Host github.com other-exception.example.com
ControlPath none

Host *
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath   ~/.ssh/%r,%h,%p
ControlPersist 30m
```

This is mentioned in the [`ssh_config`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5) man page, but not very clearly:

> For each parameter, the first obtained value will be used. 
>   The configuration files contain sections separated by “Host” specifications, and that section is only applied for hosts that match one of the patterns given in the specification.